# Expression works in form but not in calculated column Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, expression, ms-access-2016

I have an expression which works in a form but not in the calculated column, its driving me crazy. Sorry I don't know how to format the expression any better, its like that in the expression builder.

Working

```
IIf([Combo356]='Annual', 
IIf([Combo152]='Microlight',[Text129]*23.2,
IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>450 And [Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]<=3200,[Text129]*46.5,
IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>3200 And [Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]<=14000,[Text129]*300,
IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>14000,[Text129]*580,0)))), 
IIF([Combo356]='Pro Rata',
IIf([Combo152]='Microlight',(23.2*[Text369]/12) + (23.2*[Text371]/365),
IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>450 And [Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]<=3200,(46.5*[Text369]/12) + (46.5*[Text371]/365),
IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>3200 And [Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]<=14000,(300*[Text369]/12) + (300*[Text371]/365),
IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>14000,(580*[Text369]/12) + (580*[Text371]/365),
0))))))
```

Not working

```
IIf([Fee Type]='Annual', 
IIf([Type of Aircraft]='Microlight',[Duration of License]*23.2,
IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>450 And [Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]<=3200,[Duration of License]*46.5,
IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>3200 And [Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]<=14000,[Duration of License]*300,
IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>14000,[Duration of License]*580,0)))), 
IIF([Fee Type]='Pro Rata',
IIf([Type of Aircraft]='Microlight',(23.2*[Months]/12) + (23.2*[Days]/365),
IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>450 And [Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]<=3200,(46.5*[Months]/12) + (46.5*[Days]/365),
IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>3200 And [Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]<=14000,(300*[Months]/12) + (300*[Days]/365),
IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>14000,(580*[Months]/12) + (580*[Days]/365),
0))))))
```

Comment: What's the exact error message/problem?

Comment: *doesn't work* is not a helpful error description. What exactly happens? -- Is this in a query? [Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Comment: I get a syntax error in expression, no other info is given. This is not a query, its a calculated column expression in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Reformatted the 2nd expression to help clarify the structure:

```
IIf([Fee Type]='Annual', 
 IIf([Type of Aircraft]='Microlight', [Duration of License]*23.2,
  IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>450 And [Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]<=3200, [Duration of License]*46.5,
   IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>3200 And [Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]<=14000, [Duration of License]*300,
    IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>14000, [Duration of License]*580, 0
    )
   )
  )
 ), 
 IIF([Fee Type]='Pro Rata',
  IIf([Type of Aircraft]='Microlight', (23.2*[Months]/12) + (23.2*[Days]/365),
   IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>450 And [Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]<=3200, (46.5*[Months]/12) + (46.5*[Days]/365),
    IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>3200 And [Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]<=14000, (300*[Months]/12) + (300*[Days]/365),
     IIf([Maximum Take off Weight (kg)]>14000, (580*[Months]/12) + (580*[Days]/365), 0
     )
    )
   )
  ), *** NEED 3rd PARAMETER HERE ***
 )
)
```

If I'm not completely wrong, `IIF([Fee Type]='Pro Rata', ...` is missing its 3rd parameter.

I don't understand how your first expression can work.

Also, calculated columns in tables are evil, see link above. Use a query.